# Is a choke required on power supply input, 50 Hz single-phase 230 VAC

Tags: inductor, electrolytic-capacitor

I have a 2 kW 20 kHz ultrasonic power supply which trips input power when I turn it on.
I disconnected the choke between the diode bridge + and capacitor +, and connected from the bridge to the capacitor - no tripped power.

230 VAC into bridge, around 320 VDC over capacitor. Which is correct.
450 VDC 1000 µF capacitor. Tests fine, holds charge and no apparent fail signs.

I don't have a megger (an insulation tester).

Could the choke be faulty? I am seeing this problem on 4 units, all off the same machine. Failure cause to be determined.

Open line between either end of coil to laminated frame.
0.2 Ω between choke terminations.

Comment: @brhans I learned something today! I'll add that info to the question and will clean up my comments

Comment: Benjamin, I don't know the weight/mass of your choke. But I'm guessing it's `heavy` enough. I don't usually see problems with chokes of any size. They just work. Especially since you tested the obvious stuff and found things to be reasonable and expected. What do you mean by *"all off the same machine?"* Especially in the context of seeing it on "4 units." Can you explain this better?

Comment: @periblepsis Thanks for the response. These 4 units come off a bigger machine with multiple stations, if that makes sense? Seems we have isolated the issue. Circuit breaker was faulty, as was the other mains test circuit, also dropping the 2nd cb. Choke has now been wired into the AC line-in to diode bridge. The in-rush current has halved and choke is running cooler. Also, no reverse current to electronics, when powering down. Far safer now. Was pulling around 110A, around 60A now. Charge time increased from 4mS to 15mS. Capacitor will be a happy chappy now. Choke tested at 9múH